# How to call renderRow in ListView?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-listview

I'm using `ListView` in react-native. And I want to update `ListView` by function, so I used `this.setState` like this.

```
<Button onPress={()=>this.setState({word:this.state.word})}>Btn</Button>
```

And after press button, `render()` method works, but `renderRow` method not works. So `ListView` doesn't work. How can I solve it?

Here is my ListView

```
<ListView
    datasource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)}/>
```

and my _renderRow

```
_renderRow(param){
    return(
        <View>{param.word.includes(this.state.word)&&<Text>{param.word}</Text>}</View>
    );
}
```

I want to update listview when I press Button, and shows up list that param.word includes this.state.word

Comment: Post code related to list view u have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`renderRow` is triggered when the DataSource for the ListView is updated. So it seems that your button should update `this.state.dataSource` rather than `this.state.word`.

From: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html

In your constructor, you should initialise the DataSource:

```
constructor() {
  var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
  this.state = {
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2']),
  };
}
```

Then, you can register the DataSource with the ListView:

```
render() {
  return (
    <ListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>}
    />
  );
}
```

When your data changes, you can update the DataSource:

```
onDataChanged(newData) {
  var ds = this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newData);
  this.setState({dataSource: ds});
}
```

This will trigger your `renderRow` function.

Answer (score 0):

Don't miss the cloneWithRows call for the required ListViewDataSource property of the ListView Component.
[Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listviewdatasource.html) says:

> To update the data in the datasource, use cloneWithRows (or cloneWithRowsAndSections if you care about sections). The data in the data source is immutable, so you can't modify it directly. The clone methods suck in the new data and compute a diff for each row so ListView knows whether to re-render it or not.

If you initialized the DataSource in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1,r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = { datasource: ds.cloneWithRows(['A', 'B', 'C']) };
}
```

Your update function could look like:

```
fetchData() {
    //... fetching logic
    var items = ['D', 'E', 'F'];
    this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(items)
    });
}
```